# AppFabric Cache Database configuration has 1GB size

Tags: appfabric, distributed-caching, appfabric-cache

I use AppFabric cache with SQL Server-Based Cluster Configuration.

The problem is the configuration database has grown to 1GB size.

The problematic table which takes most space in db is 'ConfigAudit'.
Its full of entries with values of column 'Operation': UpdateNew, UpdateOld,
with UpdatedTimeStamps of each minute.

I can not find any information about AppFabric's cluster configuration database, nor about any audit of cache operations.

Cache works fine except this problem.

Is there a way this audit to be turned off ,
or other solution to make this database much smaller and not growing up again?

Kind regards,
Charles.

Answer (score 0):

dbo.ConfigAudit table is used to track the changes on dbo.Config table. It is mostly for diagnostics, and it cannot be changed via PowerShell commands.

To turn off the tracking, you can disable all the triggers for dbo.Config table. For example,

[image]